# set unknown_cost_value in costmap

Tags: navigation, mapping, ros-hydro, costmap, costmap-2d

[image: Rosanswers logo]

How can I set "unknown_cost_value" in costmap?

In /map there are unknown value set to -1, but when /map is converted into costmap, unknow value is set to 0, like free space.

I tried to set parameters in costmap_common_params.yaml but it doesn't works

```
   global_costmap:
   global_frame: /map
   robot_base_frame: /base_footprint
   update_frequency: 4.0
   publish_frequency: 4.0
   static_map: true
   static_layer: {enabled: true, lethal_cost_threshold: 100, track_unknown_space: true, unknown_cost_value: -1}   
   transform_tolerance: 0.5
```

Thanks

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/198255/set-unknown_cost_value-in-costmap/) by [Stefano Primatesta](https://answers.ros.org/users/9136/stefano-primatesta/) on ROS Answers with karma: 402 on 2014-11-25

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Thanks @David Lu , but I've already add:

```
   obstacle_layer: {enabled: true, lethal_cost_threshold: 100, track_unknown_space: true, unknown_cost_value: -1}
```

in costmap_common_params.yaml.

It works!

---

Originally posted by [Stefano Primatesta](https://answers.ros.org/users/9136/stefano-primatesta/) with karma: 402 on 2014-11-25

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Try setting track_unknown_space to true in the costmap namespace.

---

Originally posted by [David Lu](https://answers.ros.org/users/19/david-lu/) with karma: 10932 on 2014-11-25

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1